# Perl INC not updated when running with T flag

Tags: perl

I'm trying to modify PERLLIB in order to give access to the folder where a certain library is.

In order to do so I'm modifying the PERLLIB variable:

```
export PERLLIB=/some/folder
```

Now if I do:

```
perl
print "$_\n" for @INC;
```

The new folder is displayed. However, If I do

```
perl -wT
print "$_\n" for @INC;
```

The new folder is not displayed. Is there a way to modify INC variable with env variables with the T flag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. That would defy the point. The whole purpose of `-T` is to avoid letting the caller execute arbitrary code, and giving them control of `@INC` would allow just that.

```
$ cat script
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
print "Hello World\n";

$ printf '%s' 'print "owned\n";' >strict.pm

$ PERL5LIB=. script
owned
Hello World
```

Since `-T` is usually used by setuid scripts, allowing the caller to modify `@INC` would allow the caller to execute arbitrary code as the script owner.

You can use either of the following (but the script's setuid and setgid bits will be ignored):

```
perl -I/some/folder -T script
```

```
perl -Mlib=/some/folder -T script
```

You could add the following to the script itself if it's a setuid/setgid script:

```
use lib '/some/folder';
```

Make sure to use an absolute path, or you'll effectively invalidate `-T`.

Answer (score 5):

The [perlsec man page](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html) has this to say on [Taint mode and @INC](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Taint-mode-and-%40INC).

> When the taint mode (`-T` ) is in effect, the "." directory is removed from `@INC`, and the environment variables `PERL5LIB` and `PERLLIB` are ignored by Perl. You can still adjust `@INC` from outside the program by using the `-I` command line option as explained in [perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html). The two environment variables are ignored because they are obscured, and a user running a program could be unaware that they are set, whereas the -I option is clearly visible and therefore permitted.
>
> Another way to modify `@INC` without modifying the program, is to use the `lib` pragma, e.g.:
>
> ```
>  perl -Mlib=/foo program
> ```
>
> The benefit of using `-Mlib=/foo` over `-I/foo`, is that the former will automagically remove any duplicated directories, while the latter will not.
>
> Note that if a tainted string is added to `@INC`, the following problem will be reported:
>
> > Insecure dependency in require while running with -T switch

Comment: That first sentence is partially outdated. `.` is no longer in `@INC` to be removed.

Comment: @ikegami: Yeah, I realised that as I posted it. I'll work up a documentation patch.